# AWS Java client does not authenticate dynamo endpoint on Java 7

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

There is a simple scan call going to dynamo from my code which works fine in Java 6 and not in Java 7. The [amazon forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=76183) mention this problem and recommend disabling certificate verification, which seems risky to me. Does anyone know what changed between Java 6 & 7 to cause this issue?

3-Jul-2012 3:51:27 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
   WARNING: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works with one JRE and not another, the problem is likely that you don't have the correct CA cert installed in your 1.7 JRE keystore.  See this post for details:

http://welocally.com/?p=1358

You can also just connect to the http:// version of the Dynamo endpoint and so avoid ssl altogether (and get a nice performance boost as a result).